# Video file reading and writing

Tags: c++, video, io

If I read a video file and wrote the read bytes to another file, do I need special libraries such as FFMPEG and OpenCV to do this? Will the destination file still be a video? I would like this done on C++. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

> Open a file **A** as source + Open a file **B** as destiny + Read all bytes of
>   **A** and write in **B** = **Copy the file**

So in C++ you can use `std::ifstream` to open the file for reading and `std::ofstream` to write the file for writing... Google for it. You don't need anything else.

Comment: I've been trying this on a test video but I can't even get the size using 
`size = inFile.tellg();`

Answer (score 0):

You do need to us OpenCV to do this, the destination file will still be video because you only write the code to capture a video from file and modify it by using openCV.

For instance if you want to open a avi file you can do:

```
CvCapture* capture = 0;
capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("file.avi");
if( !capture )
{
throw "Invalid file";
}
 ......
```